# Get the specific treeview from EventArgs

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I dynamically generate a couple of treeview control in my code and point all treeviews to the same SelectedNodeChanged event. However, in the event, I cannot get the specific treeview which contains the node that was clicked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTree; i++)
{
    treeList[i] = new TreeView();
    treeList[i].SelectedNodeChanged += TreeSelectedNodeChanged;
}

private void TreeSelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // cannot call treeList[i] since all treeview should direct to this event 
    Message.Text = "You selected: " + treeList[i].SelectedNode.Text;
}
```

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sender` parameter is the control fired the event

```
private void TreeSelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected_tree_view = (TreeView)sender;
    // Just in case you need it
    var selected_tree_view_index = treeList.IndexOf(selected_tree_view);
    Message.Text = "You selected: " + selected_tree_view.SelectedNode.Text;
}
```